# How to add the hostname and current working directory to the xterm.js terminal using node-pty in electron.js

Tags: javascript, terminal, electron, xtermjs, node-pty

[image]

I want to replace the `bash-3.2` with the hostname and current working directory. (Like a vs code's integrated terminal)

I am using electron.js with xterm.js and node-pty

Tried below code to spawn node-pty process.

```
  const ptyProcess = pty.spawn(shell, [], {
    name: 'xterm-color',
    cols: 80,
    rows: 30,
    cwd: process.env.CWD,
    env: process.env,
  });
```